# How to get rid of error "Non-existing setting 'Suite Setup'" in Robot FW Python

Tags: robotframework, python-3.8

I have 2 files in my project

1. TestCase.robot
2. UserKeys.robot

UserKeys.robot file has below Setting

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     Collections
Library     difflib
Suite Setup         Connect To Database  psycopg2  ${DBName}  ${DBUser}  ${DBPass}   
Suite Teardown      Disconnect From Database
```

When I run my project I get below error:

Error in file 'Projects/POC/Resources/UserKeyWords.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Setup'.

Error in file 'Projects/POC/Resources/UserKeyWords.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Teardown'.

Not sure what I am missing !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource files cannot contain `Suite Setup` and `Suite Teardown`.

From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-file-structure):

> Additionally, the Setting table in resource files can contain only import settings (Library, Resource, Variables) and Documentation.

Comment: Thanks it helped after moving Suite Setup and Suite Teardown to other file which is not a Resource file.